# Magento 1.9 CSS file isn't loading home page

Tags: magento-1.9, css

Using Premium aspire theme. I want customize stylefrom my own css code.

1. Added css file location: **`skin/frontend/rwd/aspire/css/customstyle.css`**
2. Added **page.xml** and **local.xml**(I know any one add but just try add both file) **`app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/page.xml`**
   and
   **`app/design/frontend/rwd/aspire/layout/local.xml`**

   ```
    <action method="addItem">
       <type>skin_css</type>
       <name>css/customstyle.css</name>
    </action>
   ```

   3. Cache updated It's not view. I also get url through access **customstyle.css** unfortunately I can't view source of home page.

Please help me any other solution

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use the following in *local.xml* to include CSS:

```
  <reference name="head">
    <action method="addCss">
      <stylesheet>css/customstyle.css</stylesheet>
    </action>
  </reference>
```